# Spring Boot 2 Hikari pooling with oracle database

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, authentication, listener, hikaricp

I have a problem with Hikari connection pooling in Spring boot. I use spring boot 2.1.7 in oauth2 server 2.3.4.RELEASE program that check tokens from oracle database. when I see v$session every thing is ok but in listener.log There are many logons and logoffs. Some sessions logon and logoff during 1 second!
I change Hikari connection pooling properties according to [spring jdbc hikari connection pool - constantly logs on and off to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976262/spring-jdbc-hikari-connection-pool-constantly-logs-on-and-off-to-database) but nothing change!!
my parameters are:

```
spring.datasource.auto-commit=true
spring.datasource.connection-timeout=1000
spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.TYPE=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.minimum-idle=1
spring.datasource.pool-name=oauth-POOL
#spring.datasource.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.idle-timeout=900000
```

Comment: Try removing idle properties

Comment: Also why you need such low timeout `spring.datasource.connection-timeout=1000`? Default: 30000 (30 seconds)

Comment: I removed spring.datasource.minimum-idle and spring.datasource.idle-timeout properties and increased spring.datasource.connection-timeout to 30000 but nothing changed and When I see Listener.log there are many connect logs as you can see below:

12-JUL-2021 10:43:38 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=oracle))(SERVICE_NAME=oauth)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=172.25.250.35)(PORT=51416)) * establish * oauth * 0

Comment: Don't you have url or jdbc-url defined?

Comment: Yes, I have defined jdbc-url: `spring.datasource.username=user1
spring.datasource.password=Password123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<Some IP>:1521/oauth`