# Spring JDBC Hikari constantly logon logoffs in Oracle Database

Tags: java, spring, database, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I am using spring boot hikari db pool to connect to an Oracle database (19C).
Our properties are as below:

```
spring.datasource.app.hikari.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.app.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.app.hikari.maximumPoolSize=10
spring.datasource.app.hikari.idleTimeout=600000
spring.datasource.app.hikari.connectionTimeout=180000
spring.datasource.app.hikari.max-lifetime=60000
```

Our Database's AUD table is filling up due to constant logon logoff actions getting registered from the services every second.

I used solution from below question (to **decrease minimumIdle** and **increase idleTimeout** for long idle times), but it did not resolve the issue.

[spring jdbc hikari connection pool - constantly logs on and off to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57976262/spring-jdbc-hikari-connection-pool-constantly-logs-on-and-off-to-database)

Can somebody help in this case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you override data source configuration? HikariCP default property set are not like this

Answer (score 0):

If you have not override datasource with different property name for hikaricp then use below properties

```
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=180000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=60000
```

Comment: Thanks Mystery. I  will try above. 
Also, we did override spring properties with our application specific properties - something like - spring.datasource.myapp.hikari.*

Comment: @NileshShinde then share that code where you configure data source